# Post choice of a radiobutton into another page to send into database

Tags: php, sql, radio-button, checked

Hello I make radio button into timesheet.php

```
<!-- creation des radiobuttons pour le choix. -->
    <div id="radioover" align="center"  >
        <input type="radio" name="group"style="background-color:transparent" id="option1" onClick="getvote();" /><strong>mettre en banque </strong>
        <input type="radio" name="group" style="background-color:transparent" id="option2" onClick="getvote();" /><strong>Paye nombre d'heure</strong>
    </div>

    <div id="radiounder" align="center"></br>
        <input type="radio" name="group" style="background-color:transparent "  id="option3" onclick="getvote();" /><strong>Prendre heures en banque</strong>
        <input type="radio" name="group" style="background-color:transparent "  id="option4" onclick="getvote();" /><strong>Paye nombre d'heure</strong>
    </div>
```

and in my timesheet.php I included my real page autocomplete.php where I have my finish button

```
<input type="submit" name="submit_val"  value="Terminé" id="end" />
<input type="hidden" name="data" value="<?php echo $date; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="usrUserName" value="<?php echo $usrUserName; ?>" />
```

When I click finish i go into my insert.php page ( where is my sql to insert into database)

I need help to keep my choice of my radiobutton.

If someone check "Payenombre d'heure" (option3) i need to put into a variable X = 3
if is option 2 is checked put into x number 2. Cause when I will insert into my database I will insert X for the choice.

How I do this?

Answer (score 0):

adding the value tag to every input?

```
    <input type="radio" name="group" style="background-color:transparent" id="option2" value="2" onClick="getvote();" /><strong>Paye nombre d'heure</strong>
```

Comment: How I send it to my page insert.php cause my insert php start when I click on the button finish in autocomplete and my radiobutton is made in timehseet ( autocomplete is included is timesheet)

Comment: I understand that all the inputs are contained into a <form method="post" action"insert.php"> so you can get all the results of the form in the insert.php reviewing the $_POST variable

Comment: my radiobutton is not set into form method post as you can see.